# facebook like button and like box cannot show at same time

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, show

If I only run one of them, then it can show up properly.

If I run both of them at same time, the code who come first will show, the one who come up at bottom will not show.

I believe there's some conflict.

Anyone facing this issue?

```
<html doctype="XHTML 1.0 Transitional" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head></head>

<body>


<div class="fbLikeButton">
<fb:like show_faces="false" width="300"></fb:like>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({appId: 'XXXXXXXX', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
          };
          (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
        </script>
<br>
</div>


<!-- facebook code -->



<div align="center">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("de15667c632963d186082c258e3cc970");</script>

<fb:fan profile_id="XXXXXXXXXX" stream="0" connections="6" width="155" height="350"></fb:fan>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, it works now.

I believe it is javascript code redundancy.

Just need to remove one of the javascript reference.

I removed `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US"></script>`

Comment: This is the main and common problem when you integrate multiple facebook plugins in your system. +1 for self exploring